# @PersistenceContext(unitName="myPersistence") fails starting my TomEE Web Server

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, tomee-7

In my Eclipse dynamic web project I use JPA. I have created my connection in tomee.xml under TomEE server and it works fine. I have created a persistence.xml file as following; but if I try to add in my BusinessBean the row @PersistenceContext(unitName="myPersistence") I see the following error and the server doesn't start.

If I try to insert a random name under unitName, I see also the same error. Very strange, how can I solve the problem?

My persistence file:

```html
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistence">

    <jta-data-source>connessioneCorsoWeb</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="openejb.jpa.auto-scan" value="true" />
            <!-- <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" /> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My error:

```html
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:corso_web' did not find a matching property.
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Server version:        Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.32 (7.0.5)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Server built:          Jun 20 2018 19:50:35 UTC
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Server number:         8.5.32.0
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: OS Version:            10.13.6
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Architecture:          x86_64
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Version:           1.8.0_20-b26
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_BASE:         /Volumes/Main/Workspace/Learning/JEE2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_HOME:         /Applications/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Volumes/Main/Workspace/Learning/JEE2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Applications/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Volumes/Main/Workspace/Learning/JEE2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Applications/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5/endorsed
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:21 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/test/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:22 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:22 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:22 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:22 AM sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFORMAZIONI: Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: ********************************************************************************
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: Startup: Thu Sep 06 10:47:23 CEST 2018
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: Copyright 1999-2018 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: Version: 7.0.5
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: Build date: 20180710
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: Build time: 12:28
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: ********************************************************************************
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: openejb.home = /Applications/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.5
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFORMAZIONI: openejb.base = /Volumes/Main/Workspace/Learning/JEE2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFORMAZIONI: Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@8909f18
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFORMAZIONI: Succeeded in installing singleton service
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory init
INFORMAZIONI: TomEE configuration file is '/Volumes/Main/Workspace/Learning/JEE2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/openejb.xml'
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMAZIONI: Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMAZIONI: Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMAZIONI: Configuring Service(id=My DataSource, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMAZIONI: Configuring Service(id=My Unmanaged DataSource, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMAZIONI: Configuring Service(id=My Singleton Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Singleton Container)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMAZIONI: Configuring Service(id=My Stateful Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateful Container)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMAZIONI: Configuring Service(id=My Stateless Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentsResolver loadFrom
AVVERTENZA: File error: <Deployments dir="apps/"> - Does not exist: /Volumes/Main/Workspace/Learning/JEE2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/apps
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFORMAZIONI: Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:23 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFORMAZIONI: Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:24 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFORMAZIONI: Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:24 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFORMAZIONI: Creating Resource(id=My DataSource)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:34 AM org.apache.openejb.config.JndiEncInfoBuilder buildEjbRefs
AVVERTENZA: Unresolved ejb reference "java:comp/env/web.Activator/activeBean" in bean "corso_web.Comp".  Will attempt resolution again at runtime.
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:34 AM org.apache.openejb.config.JndiEncInfoBuilder buildEjbRefs
AVVERTENZA: Unresolved ejb reference "java:comp/env/web.Activator/activeBean" in bean "/Volumes/Main/Workspace/Learning/JEE2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/corso_web".  Will attempt resolution again at runtime.
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:34 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults logResults
GRAVE: FAIL ... corso_web:  Use of @PersistenceContext only applies to EntityManager references.  Fix ref "java:comp/env/business.PersonaBean/erisci"
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:34 AM org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults logResults
GRAVE: Invalid EjbModule(name=corso_web, path=/Volumes/Main/Workspace/Learning/JEE2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/corso_web)
Sep 06, 2018 10:47:34 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
GRAVE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso_web]
org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=corso_web)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.deploy(ReportValidationResults.java:88)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build(AppInfoBuilder.java:327)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1040)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1281)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 06, 2018 10:47:34 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
GRAVE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso_web]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:856)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1651)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1631)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1312)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 06, 2018 10:47:34 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso_web]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/corso_web]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=corso_web)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1315)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=corso_web)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.deploy(ReportValidationResults.java:88)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build(AppInfoBuilder.java:327)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:1040)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1281)
    ... 11 more

Sep 06, 2018 10:47:34 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Sep 06, 2018 10:47:34 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: `javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;` and so you can conclude that your "JPA API" jar is inconsistent with the JPA provider you are using. That method was added in JPA 2.1, so something in your environment is JPA 1.0 or 2.0

Comment: In the /lib folder of my TomEE I only have openejb-jpa-integration-7.0.5.jar, which is the latest version; and persistence-api-2.0.jar. I don't see any other file related to the name JPA. Should I check some specific library? Thank you very much

Comment: So you have JPA API v2.0, you have some version of "OpenEJB", and you also have some JPA provider ... and one of them is inconsistent with the other. End. Of.

Comment: I deleted persistence-api-2.0.jar and added javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar but all is the same. What's wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Just switch to [WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/), it has JPA 2.1 provider already integrated and you will not have to fight with all these colliding dependencies.

Comment: Whats wrong has already been answered. You have a version of TomEE, which includes a version of OpenEJB, which is built against a version of JPA API, and you are using a JPA provider also built against a JPA API jar. Only you know what you are using, but the fact is that they are inconsistent. So check your jars, versions etc etc

Comment: Ok, I will reply later. I should use TomEE, I cannot use WebSphere. I have heard that a colleague has same project under Tomcat and all works fine. Later, I will try to create a similar Tomcat with exactly same library of my colleague and I will update you about the result. Thank you very much and see you later!

Comment: Tomcat is just a web container, so you will have much more trouble if you need any additional Java EE features. And if you need completely free version of Liberty there is open source one - [Open Liberty](https://openliberty.io/). Much better than using Tomcat.

Comment: Very sorry for mistaking, I hadn't notice that the message is a little bit different if I use a different library version. I repeat, sorry for mistake! :-( Now I update the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of the injected context (`business.PersonaBean/erisci`)? Must be `EntityManager`. If you want the `EntityManagerFactory`, use `@PersistenceUnit`. If it is EntityManager it likely means your app packages a jpa api conflicting with the provided one.